# Multiple private and public key for same user

Tags: database, ssh, primary-key, public-key

If a user have 2 pairs of public and private key, how can the server that has the public keys know which one to use? The server should encrypt the message using the public key to that private key, however how does it know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. SSH does not do *Encrypt&Decrypt*, but *Sign&Verify* sequence.

The server sends some data, client signs them using its private key and server can verify the data using all of the public keys it has stored in `authorized_keys` file.

But in real world, there is optional phase before doing all the above. The client sends also the public keys to match correct public part on the server.